# Alignment inside a curve rubric

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following problem with my CV using Curve: I have two files,
namely main.tex:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper]{curve}

\usepackage[nohead,nofoot,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}

\title{CV}

\leftheader{}
\rightheader{}

\begin{document}
  \makeheaders
  \maketitle

  \makerubric{Degrees}

\end{document}
```

and a file containing a list of degrees, called "Degrees.tex":

```
\begin{rubric}{Degrees}
\entry*[2010] Bachelor of Science, Computer Science, Some University
Thesis:    "XXX"
Reviewers: "ABC"
           "DEF"


\end{rubric}
```

I would like the content of the rubric to be properly aligned, as they are in the source code, but I just can't figure out how to do that. I have tried using the tabular environment, which works but has the drawback that the text inside it is not left-justified with respect to the text above it

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 Thesis: & "XXX" \\
 Reviewers: & "ABC" \\
 & "DEF" \\
\end{tabular}
```

I also tried an itemize, but this fails completely.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[Thesis:] "XXX"
\item[Reviewers:] "ABC"
\item[] "DEF"
\end{itemize}
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the environment tabular is the best way. Your problem with the space based on the dimension `tabcolsep` To start the environment table at the left side you can set the space to 0pt by using `@{}`. More information about this command can be found in the documentation of array.

```
\begin{rubric}{Degrees}
\entry*[2010] Bachelor of Science, Computer Science, Some University

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
 Thesis: &  ``XXX"\\
 Reviewers: & ``ABC"\\
 & ``DEF"\\
\end{tabular}
\end{rubric}
```

Using this definition in your contens

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{curve}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Degrees.tex}
\begin{rubric}{Degrees}
\entry*[2010] Bachelor of Science, Computer Science, Some University

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
 Thesis: &  ``XXX"\\
 Reviewers: & ``ABC"\\
 & ``DEF"\\
\end{tabular}
\end{rubric}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[nohead,nofoot,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}
\title{CV}
\leftheader{}
\rightheader{}
\begin{document}
  \makeheaders
  \maketitle
  \makerubric{Degrees}
\end{document}
```

leads to:
[image]